# PHP. Counting number of strings satisfying an specific condition in a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, count

I'm trying to find the number of strings that satisfy some conditions in a `foreach` loop. This is what I've tried so far:

```
<?php
$list = $item->getProperty();
$n = 0;
foreach($list as $single) {
    $designation = $single->getPropertyName(); // var_dump($designation); outputs 150 strings
    if (strpos($designation, 'foo') === 0) { // var_dump($designation); outputs 5 strings containing 'foo' in their designation names
        $n++;
        echo count($n); 
    }
}
?>
```

`echo count($n);` returns `11111` instead of returning `5` which is the value I want to obtain.

Could someone help me out a bit?

Comment: 1) You're using `count` (the function) on an integer (it expects an array); `$n` is already your count. 2) You want to check/display its value *after* the loop, not on very iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$list = $item->getProperty();
$n = 0;
foreach($list as $single) {
    $designation = $single->getPropertyName(); // var_dump($designation); outputs 150 strings
    if (strpos($designation, 'foo') === 0) { // var_dump($designation); outputs 5 strings containing 'foo' in their designation names
        $n++;
    }
}
echo $n;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to achieve the same in a more *functional* and *elegant* way, you could use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
array_reduce($item->getProperty(), function($sum, $single) {
    if (strpos($single->getPropertyName(), 'foo') === 0) {
        $sum++;
    }
    return $sum;
});
```

A less readable, but more *elegant* one-line solution would look like:

```
array_reduce($item->getProperty(), function($sum, $single) { return (strpos($single->getPropertyName(), 'foo') === 0) ? ++$sum : $sum; }
```

And now that we have [short arrow functions in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.arrow-functions), you can use this if you are running on PHP 7.4:

```
array_reduce($item->getProperty(),
    fn($sum, $single) => (strpos($single->getPropertyName(), 'foo') === 0) ? ++$sum : $sum);
```